# Oracle - Rollback Segment usage

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I would like to know how can I monitor rollback segment space usage from AWR views (dba_hist views). Is there any way to indentify how many percentage of available space are used for rollback segment?

I am using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following might be what you want:

```
SELECT rn.Name "Rollback Segment", rs.RSSize/1024 "Size (KB)", rs.Gets "Gets",
       rs.waits "Waits", (rs.Waits/rs.Gets)*100 "% Waits",
       rs.Shrinks "# Shrinks", rs.Extends "# Extends"
FROM   sys.v_$rollName rn, sys.v_$rollStat rs
WHERE  rn.usn = rs.usn;
```

Comment: It's selecting from v$rollstat view (which shows rollback segment usage at a particular point of time if I am not wrong). But what I am trying to do is to monitor rollback segment usage for a period time. So I am looking for something similar to dba_hist_* view of AWR tool, but I am not sure if AWR monitor rollback segment related statstics.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: It is something like I need to get a snap shot of rollback segment usage at each hour. That's why I am wondering if there is any AWR view that contains rollback segment usage.

Comment: Ok, I would still use the above query and write out the results to a table, using DBMS_SCHEDULER or CRON to do it.  To be honest I don't know if the AWR views will show it (probably - you do get similar info in the reports)

Comment: Thanks Karl. I thought there might be something like dba_hist_sgastat which contains snapshots of v$sggstat. So it seems like I have to take snapshots of v$rollstat manually.

Answer (score -3):

1. Undo changes when a transaction is rolled back
2. Ensure other transactions do not see uncommitted changes made to the database
3. Recover the database to a consistent state in case of failures